# Is $\Bbb C[x, y]$ an irreducible representation of $\mathfrak{sl}(2, \Bbb C)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras

Consider the Lie algebra $\text{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ (commutator as Lie bracket), with its standard basis consisting of $$e=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix},\quad f=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix},\quad h=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Define the map $R: \text{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})\rightarrow \text{End}(\mathbb{C}[x,y])$ by $$h\mapsto x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}, \quad e\mapsto x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}, \quad f\mapsto y\frac{\partial}{\partial x}.$$

This realizes $(\mathbb{C}[x,y],R)$ as a representation of $\text{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$.

I want to know whether this representation is irreducible, i.e., whether there is an invariant vector subspace of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ which is not equal to $0$ or $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** Each of the basis operators preserve the total degree of any polynomial (or map that polynomial to zero).

Comment: Thanks for the hint! But I am not sure how this could help. I guess you would say that there is no such sub-v.sp.?

Comment: @user372565 The representation maps polynomials of degree $N$ to polynomials of degree $N$ or to zero, thus preserving the subspace of $N$-degree polynomials.

Comment: Where $N$ is arbitrary, right?

Comment: @user372565 Yes, $N$ is arbitrary.

Comment: A similar effect is seen in the two particle harmonic oscillator. The combined ladder operators (which happen to also satisfy $\mathfrak{su}(1,1)$..) leave the overall energy constant, but shift between the individual states within that energy level.